# Git add on repository sub directory returning 'fatal: [FOLDER] is outside repository'

Tags: git, version-control

I have a website that I need to commit system generated files and folders to an existing git repository via linux command line.

I've pulled the repo to my server, and am writing files within a sub folder of the repo, but when I run `git add [FOLDER]/*` , its giving me an error that the folder is outside the repository. I'm at a loss as to how to get past this. I'm brand new to git, please help!

Comment: You can probably just use `git add folder`. That should work for all sub-files and folders. Also, please include the *full* error message you're getting.

Comment: `git add folder/*` should work even if `folder` has not yet been added. I, too, would like to see the actual command and error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer turned out to be that I was using an absolute path when doing git add /path/to/folder/* instead of cd /path/to/folder/;git add *;

For some reason git didnt like the absolute path and was choking on it. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual commands, I can only take an educated guess.  The error `<blah> is outside repository` usually comes from when you try to add a directory that is not actually a subdirectory of the repository.

For example, if you try to add something like `../blah` or using an absolute directory like `/blah`.

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/test/.git/
$ git add ../blah
fatal: ../blah: '../blah' is outside repository
$ git add /blah
fatal: /blah: '/blah' is outside repository
```

There's no need to add a subdirectory before you add files to it.  Git does not track directories anyway, only what's in those directories.  `git add subdir/*` and `git add subdir` are (almost) the same command.

```
$ mkdir stuff
$ touch stuff/things
$ git add stuff/*
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   stuff/things
```

But `git add subdir/*` should be avoided as it will miss things like dotfiles.

```
$ touch stuff/.dot
$ git add stuff/*
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   stuff/things

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    stuff/.dot
```

Use `git add subdir` instead.

```
$ git add stuff
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   stuff/.dot
    new file:   stuff/things
```